# Swift protocol and extension, I need to call overridden method or default extension method as per requirement

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a protocol Vehicle and its extension like below:

```
protocol Vehicle {
    func Drive()    
}

extension Vehicle {
    func Stop() {
        print("iiiich...")
    }
}
```

And I also have declaration like below for Stop Method

```
struct Car: Vehicle {
    func Drive() {
        print("Can Drive")
    }
    func Stop() {
        print("yo stop")
    }
}

let myCar = Car()
myCar.Drive()
myCar.Stop()
```

But its override the Stop Method

```
// Output
// Can Drive
// yo stop
```

And as per my requirement I need default method sometime and some time overridden method definition

Comment: Please note - func names in Swift (along with variables and parameters) should begin with lowercase letters.

Comment: if you don't want to override the method, just don't override it every time, but override it when you need it – what was your issue with that approach?

Comment: Its not a issue @holex as if we conform the protocol by object it uses static dispatch and if you don't conform protocol its dynamic so it depends on the requirement, so we can call both methods by this or without this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey I got the answers that is to conform the protocol by the object call your default method rather than overriddedn, so we can call both defination as required

```
let honda: Vehicle = Car()
honda.Drive()
honda.Stop()
// Output
// Can Drive
// iiiich..
```

When we create a variable without type then this is static dispatch when a object conform a protocol only.

Comment: yes you should call super.Stop() inside stop implementation

Answer (score 7):

If you need the method declared in the protocol extension, just make the compiler think that the car is of type `Vehicle`:

```
let myCar = Car()
(myCar as Vehicle).Stop()
```

Comment: yes I got the notification. which is why i wrote above message

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the answers, the generic solution is to make sure that the instance that calls `Stop()` method is of type `Vehicle` (not `Car`). Nevertheless I would mention what's the logic behind it.

Personally, I think that there is a possibility to face this issue when it comes to work with the POP paradigm. Protocol extensions is a handy way the apply *Polymorphism* in our code, however it does leads to this "weird" behavior!

### Static Dispatch:

Firstly, keep in mind that it is *not* a bug. In case of:

```
let honda: Vehicle = Car()
honda.Drive()
honda.Stop()
```

there is a manual cast to the `honda` as `Vehicle`, at this point the compiler will use ***[static dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_dispatch)***, which means that it would be recognizable which method should be called (`Vehicle().Stop` or `Car().Stop`) during the compile time. It selects the default implementation for `Vehicle` which is implemented in the extension, without the need of checking what is the concrete type.

### Dynamic Dispatch:

In case of:

```
let myCar = Car()
myCar.Drive()
myCar.Stop()
```

nothing special goes here, it works exactly as expected. That's exactly the the meaning of ***[dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)***, which leads to apply *polymorphic* operations during the run time.

To make it more clear, consider that you have another  type that conforms to `Vehicle` protocol:

```
struct Bus: Vehicle {
    func Drive() {
        print("Bus Drive")
    }
    func Stop() {
        print("Bus stop")
    }
}

let myBus = Bus()
myCar.Drive()
myCar.Stop()
```

Obviously, the `print("Bus stop")` is the one which will be called, and actually that's the expected! The compiler is "smart" enough to recognize which method to be selected based on what is the concrete type (`Bus().Stop`).

**Furthermore:**

For better understanding of what's going on here, reviewing [Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/) Apple session might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a protocol with a default implementation that allows a struct param, that can do custom behaviors:

```
import UIKit

struct Car{
    //Any properties

    func drive(){
        print("Yo Drive")
    }
    func stop(){
        print("Yo Stop")
    }
}

protocol Vehicle {
    func drive(vehicle : Car?)
    func stop(vehicle : Car?)
}
extension Vehicle where Self: UIViewController {
    func drive(vehicle : Car? = nil) {
        if (vehicle != nil){
            vehicle?.drive()
        }else{
            print("drive default behavior")
        }
    }
    func stop(vehicle : Car? = nil) {
        if (vehicle != nil){
            vehicle?.stop()
        }else{
            print("stop default behavior")
        }
    }
}

class ViewController : UIViewController, Vehicle {

    func driving() {
        drive() //will print drive default behavior
        stop()  //will print stop default behavior
        let car = Car()
        drive(vehicle: car) //will print yo drive!
        stop(vehicle: car)  //will print yo Stop!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        driving()
    }
}
```